# How to load only the content area when click submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My code is like this :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Loading</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            This is header
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
            This is navigation
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <form action="test2.php" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="first_name"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="last_name"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="age"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hobby</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="hobby"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" Value="Submit"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            This is footer
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The complete code of test1.php : http://pastebin.com/idcGms0h

The complete code of test2.php : http://pastebin.com/rvBPTrhn

I want to load only the content area and skip header, navigation and footer loading

Besides that, I also want to add loading

Seems to use ajax, but I am still confused

How to load only the content area when click submit button?

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: dont use `type of submit change it to button`. when you use submit it will submit your form and reload the page. give this a try and come back if what is the result

Comment: @guradio, Ok. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use ajax. please try this instead

before submit

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Loading</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            This is header
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
            This is navigation
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <form action=""  id="info">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="first_name"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="last_name"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="age"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hobby</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="hobby"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                         <td></td>

                    </tr>
                </table>

            </form>
        </div>
       <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        <div id="footer">
            This is footer
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var postData = "text";
  $('#submit').on('click',function(){
      $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "test2.php",
            data:  $("#info").serialize(),
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
             success: function(response) { // on success..
            $('#content').html(response); // update the DIV
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        })
    });

</script>
```

[before submit form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ykX3.jpg)

test2.php contents

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td> <?php echo $_POST['first_name']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo $_POST['last_name']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo $_POST['age']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hobby</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo $_POST['hobby']; ?></td>
            </tr>
```

[after submit form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcgoL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> You need to use ajax . to update only a part of the page. firstly,give
>   unique id's to form elements
>   1. i have given form an id regForm 
>   2. submit button an id submitButton

you can either listen to form submit or click of the submit button

listening to the click of submit button ....

```
$("input#submitButton").on("click",function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var data = $('form#regForm').serialize();
   $.ajax({
           url: "test2.php",
           method: "POST",
           data: { data : data },
           dataType: "html"
   })

   .done(function( responseData ) {
       console.log("theresponse of the page is"+responseData);
       $("div#content").empty();
       ///now you can update the contents of the div...for now i have just entered text "hey i m edited" ....and i have considered that you will echo out html data on test2.php .....so specified data type as html in ajax.
       $("div#content").html("hey i m edited");
    })

   .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
     console.log("error occured");
    });



})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to use jquery ajx for that.istead of writting a big code you can just use this plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ when you using this plugin  you don't have to change anything of your form (except setting a form ID)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:   '#output',   //this is the element that show respond after ajax finish

    }; 

    // bind to the form's submit event 
    $('#myForm').submit(function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

Change your form like that:

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post" id="myForm">
```